# Adjust Border Radius on button when div is collapsed/hidden/not active

Tags: javascript, css

I am using the Collapsible divs code from here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_collapsible.asp

And I had asked here how to make the divs visible by default & that was answered here: [Make Collapsible Divs NOT hidden by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61381157/make-collapsible-divs-not-hidden-by-default)

But, now I have a problem with my CSS because, I have added border-radius to mine. So when it's open, it works fine - it has a rounded border around the whole .collapsible/.inside pair, but when it's closed I don't know how to have the rounded border on the .container button (because how I have the code makes the bottom of the collapsible not rounded) - how to I give "not active" CSS code, I guess?

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;

    if (!content.style.display || content.style.display === "block") {
      content.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      content.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.collapsible {
  background-color: #007784;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 97%;
  border:2px solid #000000;
  border-bottom:0px;
  border-radius:15px 15px 0px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin-top:3px;
  padding:2px;
}

.collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #0066FF;
  border-bottom:0px;
  border-radius:15px 15px 0px 0px;
  margin-top:3px;
}

.active {
  background-color: #007784;
  border-bottom:0px;
  border-radius:15px 15px 0px 0px;
  margin-top:3px;
}

.inside {
  padding: 0;
  width: 97%;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-top:0px;
  border-left: 2px solid #000000;
  border-right: 2px solid #000000;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius:0px 0px 15px 15px;
}



/*unrelated coding*/
table.trials {border:0; border-collapse:collapse; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; text-align:center; background-color:#000000; border-radius:15px; }
table.trials tr td {border: 1px solid #000000;}
table.trials tr td:first-child {border-left:0;}
table.trials tr td:last-child {border-right:0;}
table.trials tr:last-child td {border-bottom:0;}
.trials tr:last-child td:first-child {border-radius:0px 0px 0px 13px;}
.trials tr:last-child td:last-child {border-radius:0px 0px 13px 0px;}
td {background-color:#FFFFFF;}
td.NA {background-color:#CCCCCC;}
.divider td {height:3px; padding:0px; background-color:#000000;}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="collapsible">CH &mdash; Conformation Champion &nbsp; <span style="font-size:14px; font-weight:normal; font-style:italic;">total: 15 pts / 3 Majors</span></button>
<div class="inside" style="padding:0;"><!------------CH - Conformation Champion------------------------------------------------------>
<table class="trials" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2px" style="width:100%; margin:0; border-radius:0;">
  <tr><!------DATE: Weekday &mdash; Month ##, YYYY------->
    <td width="25%">Saturday &ndash; August 20, 2016</td>
    <td width="25%">Sunday &ndash; September 11, 2016</td>
    <td width="25%">Sunday &ndash; January 22, 2017</td>
 <td width="25%">Sunday &ndash; May 7, 2017</td>
  </tr>
  <tr><!------HOST CLUB---------------------------------->
    <td width="25%">Olympic Kennel Club</td>
    <td width="25%">Eugene Kennel Club</td>
    <td width="25%">Tualatin Kennel Club</td>
 <td width="25%">Olympia Dog Fanciers Association</td>
  </tr>
  <tr><!------LOCATION: Venue &mdash; City, State-------->
    <td width="25%">Enumclaw, WA</td>
    <td width="25%">Brownsville, OR</td>
    <td width="25%">Portland, OR</td>
 <td width="25%">Elma, WA</td>
  </tr>
  <tr><!------JUDGE-------------------------------------->
    <td width="25%">Judge: Adrian Woodfork</td>
    <td width="25%">Judge: Nancy Simmons</td>
    <td width="25%">Judge: John Ronald</td>
 <td width="25%">Judge: Roger Pritchard</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="award"><!------SCORE/PLACE/POINT------------>
    <td width="25%"><i class="W">WB</i> &mdash; 1 pt</td>
    <td width="25%"><i class="W">WB</i> / <i class="BOW">BOW</i> / <i class="BOS">BOS</i> &mdash; 2 pts</td>
    <td width="25%"><i class="W">WB</i> &mdash; 1 pt</td>
 <td width="25%"><i class="W">WB</i> &mdash; 3 pt Major</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="divider"><td colspan="4"></td></tr><!--------------------------------DIVIDER-------------------------------->
  <tr><!------DATE: Weekday &mdash; Month ##, YYYY------->
    <td width="25%">Monday &ndash; May 29, 2017</td>
    <td width="25%">Sunday &ndash; June 25, 2017</td>
    <td width="25%">Monday &ndash; July 10, 2017</td>
 <td width="25%" class="NA">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr><!------HOST CLUB---------------------------------->
    <td width="25%">Kennel Club of the California Sierra</td>
    <td width="25%">Clackamas Kennel Club</td>
    <td width="25%">Puyallyp Valley Dog Fanciers</td>
 <td width="25%" class="NA">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr><!------LOCATION: Venue &mdash; City, State-------->
    <td width="25%">Placerville, CA</td>
    <td width="25%">Canby, OR</td>
    <td width="25%">Puyallup, WA</td>
 <td width="25%" class="NA">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr><!------JUDGE-------------------------------------->
    <td width="25%">Judge: Pat Hastings</td>
    <td width="25%">Judge: Minna-Liisa Koltes</td>
    <td width="25%">Judge: Sheila DiNardo</td>
 <td width="25%" class="NA">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="award"><!------SCORE/PLACE/POINT------------>
    <td width="25%"><i class="W">WB</i> / <i class="BOW">BOW</i> / <i class="BOS">BOS</i> &mdash; 3 pt Major</td>
    <td width="25%"><i class="W">WB</i> / <i class="BOW">BOW</i> &mdash; 1 pt</td>
    <td width="25%"><i class="BOB">BOB</i> &mdash; 4 pt Major</td>
 <td width="25%" class="NA">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a CSS rule

```
button.collapsible.active {
    border-radius: 15px;
}
```

This says when the button has *both* the `collapsible` and the `active` classes the border radius should be 15px all around.

Additionally I would avoid directly manipulating `content.style.display` and make the display block or none also based on classes.

Comment: Thank you - that worked! I wasn't sure what the difference was with the .active CSS item, that was part of the original code when it was collapsed by default, so what does that work with now?

Comment: And what would you do differently with the JavaScript if you wouldn't manipulate the content.style.display? Should that be answered on the other thread I linked to?

Comment: I don't mind for you to answer that here, someone just told me to start this new topic when I asked this follow up question on my other topic, so I didn't know how much that mattered...

Comment: @BluSkye218 - yes, if you have a followup question it _should_ be a separate question, but I'm sure it's already asked and answered — I'll look for one and link to it, but the short answer is you should manipulate classes for that also such as having a div that is `<div class="collabsible">` (when visible) and _add_ the class _collapsed_ to indicate the _state_ of being collapsed (hidden) so it's `<div class="collapsible collapsed">`. Since you already have a state "active" you could use that for both purposes… active = square bottom + display block, w/o active = round + display none.

Comment: @BluSkye218 I couldn't find a good SO Q/A to link, I think since it's a matter of opinion and opinion is generally off-topic on SO, but here's a mention on [quirksmode](https://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2005/07/benchmark_tests.html) "…should be a Best Practice, since it honours the separation of behaviour and presentation" (old post, but I learned a **ton** from quirksmode when I was starting). CSS classes are great to indicate _what kind of thing_ something is, and what it's _state_ is; so `<div class="accordion collapsed">` the thing _is_ an accordion and is currently _collapsed_.